# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "torito"?

Tags: etimología, méxico, palabras-raras

He leido la palabra *[torito](http://dle.rae.es/torito)* con el siguiente significado, obtenido de la RAE:

> 4. m. Méx. Pregunta capciosa de difícil respuesta.

¿Cuál es la etimología? ¿Tiene que ver con alguna fiesta taurina?

Comment: Añadí la referencia. Si preguntas sobre el contexto, encontré la palabra en un foro. Decía "Torito" y luego una pregunta retante.

Comment: Solo para aclara un ejemplo es: "Ese problema es un torito." Es decir que es difícil.

Comment: Yo imagino la verónica que hace el que pregunta al que responde, cuando se deja en evidencia que la pregunta era capciosa, como gritándole "¡olé!, venías derecho a embestirme y te dejé peinado". Tal vez _torito_ provenga de _torear_.

Answer (score 1):

Tiene entonces diferentes significados dependiendo del contexto:

Existe una Película de la época de oro del cine mexicano que se llama “[Nosotros los pobres](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosotros_los_pobres)” donde se abordan entre otras cosas los problemas de Pepe un carpintero a quién además todos apodan El toro. Este hombre pertenecía  a la clase social baja del  México de aquella época y va de infortunio en infortunio. En una escena después de perder a su hijo, quien sería "el torito", grita la ahora popular palabra a causa del  afecto y la angustia de haber perdido a su único hijo. [Torito](http://www.dvdenlinea.com/cgi-bin/10mas.cgi?tipo=6&especifico=3)

Esta película fue muy popular en su época y aún en estos días se sigue manteniendo el “Torito” como una palabra que denota algún hecho difícil o alguna tribulación o pesar.

El otro significado podría ser el que mencionas y podría efectivamente venir de la relación entre la cornada que puede provocar un toro y el "daño" que podría ocasionarte el no saber que contestar ante una pregunta dificil e importante.

Sin embargo yo la he escuchado más en el primer contexto.

Answer (score 1):

No tiene que ver con la película. Un torito es una pregunta aparentemente sencilla pero de difícil respuesta, y generalmente se arroja con cierta malicia. Ya sea a manera de broma, o para "bajarle los humos" a una persona que se cree sabiondo y lo haces que falle en una pregunta aparentemente fácil.

Un torito muuuuy obvio podría ser... por ejemplo, preguntarte por qué las Islas Canarias reciben ese nombre, la respuesta aparentemente simple (por un canario) es incorrecta, la respuesta acertada es muy clara y lógica (por los perros... o canes). La respuesta correcta no es tan difícil, pero difícilmente le acertarán ya que hay una aparente respuesta obvia a la vista por la que todos se irán, pero esta es incorrecta.

Esa misma denominación se puede aplicar en cualquier cosa que tenga una respuesta aparentemente evidente, pero que sea errónea. En matemáticas también se usa esa expresión, cuando el profesor les pone a sus alumnos un problema cuya solución es aparentemente simple, pero resulta que se soluciona de una manera completamente diferente a como uno piensa a simple vista (Seguro te aplicaron eso varias veces cuando estudiaste álgebra o cálculo en la escuela).

Comment: Ajá, pero ¿por qué?